# unable to upload file of size more than 1 MB using multipart request, /upload_c8f18d91_ba00_4810_96de_422cdd2e9b75_00000016.tmp (Permission denied)

Tags: spring-mvc, file-upload, multipart

I am trying to write a file in a folder of a remote system using multipart request , While uploading size greater than 1 MB getting error:

"stacktrace":["org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. /upload_c8f18d91_ba00_4810_96de_422cdd2e9b75_00000016.tmp (Permission denied)

I tried setting some properties in app.properties file

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
spring.http.multipart.file-size-threshold=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size = 10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size = 10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=10MB
```

Controller method :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = PcoCloudServicesController.PATH, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@MultipartConfig(
    location = "/tmp",
    fileSizeThreshold = 10485760,
    maxFileSize = 10485760,
    maxRequestSize = 10485760)
public class PcoCloudServicesController {
  private static final String TENANT_ID = "tenantId";
  @PostMapping("/writefile")
  public JsonNode writeFileToFolderInPco(
      HttpServletRequest request,
      @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
      @RequestParam("file-data") String fileData) {
    logger.debug(
        "Controller method for writing file payload: {} and name: {}",
        file,
        file.getOriginalFilename());
    IPCoCloudServices pcoService =
        PCoCloudServicePersistance.getInstance(
            (String) request.getAttribute(StringConstants.TENANT_ID));
    return pcoService.writeFileToFolderInPco(file, fileData);
  }
}
}
```

Here I tried with @MultipartConfig annotation still unable to parse the request /upload_c8f18d91_ba00_4810_96de_422cdd2e9b75_00000016.tmp (Permission denied)

Full stacktrace:

```
"stacktrace":["org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. /upload_c8f18d91_ba00_4810_96de_422cdd2e9b75_00000016.tmp (Permission denied)","\tat org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.handleParseFailure(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:123)","\tat org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:114)","\tat org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:87)","\tat org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:71)","\tat org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartResolutionDelegate.resolveMultipartArgument(MultipartResolutionDelegate.java:98)","\tat org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.resolveName(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:164)","\tat org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:107)","\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:126)","\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:166)","\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)","\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)","\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)","\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)","\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)","\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)","\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)","\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)","\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)","\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)","\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)","\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)","\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)","\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)","\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)","\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)","\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)","\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)","\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)","\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)","\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)","\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)","\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)","\tat org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)","\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)","\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)","\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)","\tat org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)","\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)","\tat org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)","\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)","\tat org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176)","\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)","\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)","\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)","\tat org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)","\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)","\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)","\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)","\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)","\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)","\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)","\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)","\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)","\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)","\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)","\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)","\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)","\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)","\tat com.sap.hcp.cf.logging.servlet.filter.RequestLoggingFilter.doFilterRequest(RequestLoggingFilter.java:123)","\tat com.sap.hcp.cf.logging.servlet.filter.RequestLoggingFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggingFilter.java:74)","\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)","\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)","\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)","\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)","\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)","\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)","\tat com.sap.xs.java.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:66)","\tat ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve.invoke(LogbackValve.java:256)","\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)","\tat com.sap.xs.security.UserInfoValve.invoke(UserInfoValve.java:19)","\tat com.sap.xs.statistics.tomcat.valve.RequestTracingValve.invoke(RequestTracingValve.java:43)","\tat com.sap.xs.logging.catalina.RuntimeInfoValve.invoke(RuntimeInfoValve.java:40)","\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:679)","\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)","\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)","\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)","\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)","\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)","\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)","\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)","\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)","\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)","\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:836)","Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. /upload_c8f18d91_ba00_4810_96de_422cdd2e9b75_00000016.tmp (Permission denied)","\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2950)","\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2811)","\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParts(RequestFacade.java:1084)","\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParts(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:347)","\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParts(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:347)","\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParts(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:347)","\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParts(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:347)","\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParts(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:347)","\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParts(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:347)","\tat org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:94)","\t... 81 more","Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. /upload_c8f18d91_ba00_4810_96de_422cdd2e9b75_00000016.tmp (Permission denied)","\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:297)","\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2902)","\t... 90 more","Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /upload_c8f18d91_ba00_4810_96de_422cdd2e9b75_00000016.tmp (Permission denied)","\tat java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)","\tat java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)","\tat java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)","\tat java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)","\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.DeferredFileOutputStream.thresholdReached(DeferredFileOutputStream.java:151)","\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.ThresholdingOutputStream.checkThreshold(ThresholdingOutputStream.java:200)","\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.ThresholdingOutputStream.write(ThresholdingOutputStream.java:126)","\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:105)","\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:68)","\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:293)","\t... 91 more"] }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling a bit , finally I found what was causing the actual issue.
In Spring Dispatcher Servlet there is no default Multi part resolver.
So we need to inject a bean with name "multipartResolver" like this :

```
 @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
  public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
      CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
      multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(10485760);
      return multipartResolver;
  }
```

Here using setMaxUploadSize method I defined the max file size I want to support .
it solve my max file size issue. 
But here we need to catch the MaxUploadSizeExceededException in common Exception handler Class.
For more details you can go through this link https://www.baeldung.com/spring-maxuploadsizeexceeded